# pandas and matplotlib not installed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pip, python-wheel

I am using Docker and python3. I am trying to install some libraries but I have some issues. For example I was able to install numpy with pip3 install numpy, but I cannot install properly pandas and matplotlib;

I get the following problems:

```
Failed building wheel for pandas    
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
```

Can someone help with these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can install Ananconda Server from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which has all these packages bundled by default.

Then you can install additional packages via `conda install <pkg_name>`

Comment: Thx. I actually tryied it with anaconda, but there were some technical issues for me to use it at work. However, I found the solutios at another post.